# Minimization of a product

Tags: calculus

I am interested in finding the $x_i$ which minimize
$$
\prod_{i=1}^K \frac{1}{x_i}
$$
where the $x_i \in (0,1]$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i =1$. In particular I see that if $K=1$ we get $x_1=1$, and if $K=2$ we should take $x_1=x_2=\frac{1}{2}$.

I suspect that we should take $x_i =\frac{1}{K}$ in general, and how can we prove it?

Thanks so much for any help you can give.

Comment: Use Lagrange multipliers!

Comment: Maximise $\prod_{i=1}^K x_i$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^K x_i = 1$ using Lagrange multipliers. The gradient of $\mathcal L(x,\lambda)$ will have a very pleasing form.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to maximize $\prod_{i=1}^K x_i$ under the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^K x_i  = 1$.  Towards this end, one effective method is to use the [method of Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

Alternatively, note that this is simply an application of the [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).  With a little exploration on this site and elsewhere, you should find as many proofs of this as you could hope for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lagrange multipliers, we want to minimize

$\prod{x_i^{-1}}+\lambda(x_1+\cdots+x_n-1)$

by setting all partial derivatives to 0.

This yields

$$\lambda=-x_j^{-1}\prod{x_i^{-1}}$$
for all $j$, so the $x_i$ are all equal.